# SOLR: Numeric Range Queries with Strings

Tags: solr, solrj

As far as I know *Solr* does not have support for *BigDecimals*.
So I thought I'd be storing "strings" instead of "numbers".
The problem now is that range queries will not treat the
whole text as numbers.

So my range query "1 TO 10"
would return something like {1, 10} because of the ordering of
strings ->
1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7, 8, 9

I was wondering, if I could
somehow make *Solr* treat the text as a number through analyzers
or something.

Thanks,

Comment: So are you trying to do range queries on something like: myField:[0.111 TO 1.646]?

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate field for storage where you prefix the string with 0s, making all strings the same size. This is the same as defining decimal(x,2), where you get the precision you need for each part (ahead of the point and after the point).

Another option is to use a long value (64-bit) and divide it by 100 (or the precision you need) when you retrieve it again (as long as you can fit your values inside 2^53).

Both these fields would only need to be indexed and not stored (since they're meta-versions of existing fields only to be used for range searches).